# st2 components are not running in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: package, reload, status

While giving the command st2ctl reload, getting **unauthorized packages** and **st2 components are not running.**

Please find below..

2020-02-11 05:45:28,065 INFO [-] Registered 0 configs.

st2 components status

st2actionrunner is not running.
st2api is not running.
st2stream is not running.
st2auth is not running.
st2garbagecollector is not running.
st2notifier is not running.
st2resultstracker is not running.
st2rulesengine is not running.
st2sensorcontainer is not running.
st2chatops is not running.
st2timersengine is not running.
st2workflowengine is not running.
st2scheduler is not running.
root@120098fcfd22:/# st2ctl status